Film Identification - Nazi POW camp where guards leave and inmates pretend to have laryngitus
I saw a film a long time ago (probably early 1990s, but I'd have thought it was a lot older) and I've been trying to identify it. It's set in a Nazi prisoner of war camp during the second world war. All I can remember about it is that for some reason the German guards all leave and the inmates have to run the place. The Gestapo are due for an inspection and the inmates feel the best thing to do is to split into two groups - half will stay as prisoners, the other half dress up as guards. Unfortunately not many can speak German and so they pretend there's an epidemic of laryngitis to explain why most can't speak.
In the end

 The Americans come and free the camp, but the chief British officer who had pretended to be the camp chief is left behind because he'd got so into the role and had made life a misery for the others. He claimed he was British but one of the rescuing Americans kicked him in the groin - he falls down shouting in German because he'd trained himself too well to fit in as a German.


I believe that this is the film you are after: Stalag Luft from 1993.

During World War II, some Commonwealth prisoners are trying to escape from a German prison camp. Because they are old and weak, the Germans decide to escape with them. Just after the Germans are outside, the prisoners take control of the camp. Some will act as prisoners, some as Germans. 

It was a TV movie from ITV in the UK I think.  Absolutely brilliant if I remember correctly.  Stephen Fry was outstanding.

Echo this. Underrated movie, but absolutely brilliant.

Only took me 15 years to track that down! Thanks. Would never have considered looking for a comedy from what I remembered!

In fairness, from what I remember, while funny in places, it was kind of dark in others.
